# How can I append an array as an element to another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, append

So I have lots of arrays of the form:

```
$e = array( 
  "key1" => "value1",
  "key2" => "value2",
  "key3" => "value3",
  "key4" =? "value4"
);
```

And another array just declared as:

```
$a = array( );
```

What I want is to append $e to $a as an element, so

```
$a[0] = array( 
  "key1" => "value1",
  "key2" => "value2",
  "key3" => "value3",
  "key4" =? "value4"
);
```

So I can then go:

```
$count = count( $a );
for ( $j = 0; $j < $count; $j++ )
{
  echo $a[$j]["key1"];
}
```

and it will print "value1".

I will be repeating this process for all of the $e, so $a may not always be empty when the $e is appended - it may have had other $e appended previously. I thought that array_push would do this but it doesn't. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is pretty simple:

```
$a[] = $e;
```

and then do it again for any additional arrays. That will fill in the $a array starting with index zero and incrementing up.

If you wanted to use some sort of keys, you could do:

```
$a['firstarray'] = $e;
```

and accomplish much the same thing. The difference is that since keys must be unique, a screwup in that second method could overwrite an existing element. The first method has no chance of that happening.

Comment: Also using $a[] instead of array_push is a tad faster for items less than 100k

Comment: The $a[] method was the first thing I tried, before array_push, but that didn't work either. Anyway, I guess I'll work something out...

Comment: LOL, it was a typo in my code, the $a[] method did work after all. I guess typos are a lot harder to make when using 1-letter variable names like in the example I gave above ;)